# AWS Dynamo DB Query to extract the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

require downloading data from the Dynamodb table containing the "skey": "HolidayDetails" records.

Used the query below to extract the data, but it only extracting a small number of records rather than all of them.

Did i missed anything in the query. I appreciate your help in advance.

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name testing-table \
--filter-expression "skey=:s" \
--query "Items[*]" \
--expression-attribute-values "{\":s\":{\"S\":\"HolidayDetails\"}}" \
--output text > store.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the code which you shared above, which uses the CLI then you should get all the results as the CLI [paginates by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html).

As long as you do not use `--limit` or `--no-paginate` then you should have the full result set that has a string attribute `skey` which is exactly equal to `HolidayDetails`. Both key name and value are case sensitive.